# Is it professional to use personal contacts in other companies to solve problems at work?

Tags: professionalism, communication, company-policy, it-industry

I work in IT, and like typical IT folks, have a lot of friends in IT.
Is it professional to use these connections to help my employer?

For example, a client in my company needs to contact another company for things like product support or network reconfiguration. They are unsure of things like, which department to contact, what information is needed, mode of communication (email/phone), contact information (email address/phone number).

I have a friend who works at this company, so I ask them (via IM) if they know anything about it. My friend happily volunteers helpful information (the precise data you should include, the public department email, etc.) without giving out personal phone numbers or emails.

Can I pass this information along in my company and say that I got it from a personal contact in the other company?

Comment: Is it your job to provide this information? Are you supposed to know it? If yes, why don't you? Your phrasing makes it sound like you want to subcontract to friends without company permission or reimbursement (which is bad), but your example is very far from that.

Comment: For my example, I was part of a three-way conversation, somebody is implementing a change, we provide some of the necessary services to get it done, the other organisation provides the rest.  It's technically the responsibility of the area requesting the change to know how to raise their service providers, but they mentioned to us that they had no idea how to raise the other guys.

Comment: For what it's worth, that exactly what you are doing when you post something on a forum like this or the more technical [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/). The only difference is that here you are talking to strangers rather than someone you know personally.

Comment: Totally fine.  I once solved an email problem in ~3 days by contacting the technical contact email address recorded in DNS whois record for the recipient domain.   Six months later I got a reply to my original enquiry through proper channels.

Comment: "Someone in my organisation needs to contact their organisation..." Saying "their organization" makes it sound like they work for some other organization, while saying "in my organization" makes it sound like they work for yours. Which is it? Do they work for another organization but inside your network, or do they work for yours and connect to clients?

Comment: @jpmc26 The client who needs to make contact is internal to our organisation. We are an internal service provider who does some things for them, my friend works for an external service provider who does some things for them. They should be aware who to engage to get their stuff done, but at times of rapid growth our org can work in a kind of fog - for instance, the reason they need to contact my friend's org at all is because we absorbed yet another org that had an existing contract with my friend's org. You're right, I should probably find a better way to phrase that...phrase.

Comment: @Bruno Thanks. Please clarify in the question for future readers. ;)

Comment: @Dukeling: "Are you supposed to know it? If yes, why don't you?" - well, how do you expect anyone to know anything they are supposed to know unless they learn it - such as from other people who know about it before them? And even so, work in IT is very often not about "knowing" something and then repeating it, it is about knowing something and finding ways to apply it to a given problem. And that "finding ways" is a fundamentally interactive process that almost invariably involves discussions, brainstorming sessions, etc., together with other people.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You seem to be talking about learning from others (which is good) when this question appears to be about getting raw non-generalisable data from external parties to do one's day-to-day job (which tells me there's a problem somewhere). At least that's how I'm reading it.

Comment: @Dukeling: The required information appears to be specific to the company in question. It is thus inherently not generalizable, as unfortunate as that is. And, yes, unfortunately, plenty of times external organizations you work for in some way just expect *you* know how *they* work internally (no matter if it's about internal procedures as described in this question, or if they want you to configure their server without being able to tell you which DB access to use, etc.). Yes, there's an underlying problem, but the OP probably shouldn't hold their breath waiting for it to get fixed.

Comment: @Dukeling, if my employer is asking me to do something which I don't know how to do, my question isn't "why don't I know how to do this", but "why am I being asked to do something beyond my skillset". If they still expect me to do it, I would have no issue "sub-contracting" to friends.

Comment: I have to say this is certainly a viable "modus operandi" for Getting Things Done (Right). Having a large network, helping out others, collecting IOUs along the way will be of priceless value to you in a time of necessity. Be careful though, this requires knowledge about what is correct legally and ethically - don't overstep that boundary.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Assuming none of the information your friend is providing contravenes any NDA or similar then I don't see a problem with it. If you were pressuring a friend to reveal information their employer forbade them from revealing to those outside the company that would be a different story but as described? Totally normal.

Comment: For the reasons you've stated in your question, this is correct - you're simply short-cutting the Googling and tail-chasing.

Comment: What if the person you supposed to contact is yourself?  I am working with another business, and when I inquired who to contact concerning an issue, they relayed my inquiry to a relative of mine who works there.  My relative then provided my semi-private contact details.  Which was then relayed back to me.  Everyone had a good laugh.

Comment: Agreed - it really depends on the level of information you're looking for. "A friend of mine works for a company who deals with Bob's Widgets a lot - he might know a good person to speak to there" is probably fine. "My friend might be able to put me in touch with his company's account manager so we can bypass the normal service routes" is likely to be overstepping the mark.

Comment: This is AKA `Networking`

Answer (score 39):

(*The [previous version](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/97713/2) of this answer was criticized as being too over-the-top which was not intended, so I have reorganized it for more clarity.*)

The key point here is **keep your manager in the loop**.

From your description, it appears that your company is a customer of the other company. Check with your manager if there are any issues with contacting the other company's employees directly for official purposes. If there are none, then just inform him that you would be using personal contact to help with the client's requests. If there are, then no matter how silly it is in practice, you will have to do what the manager says.

A simple request like asking for contact information is usually not an issue, but it is a good idea to keep your manager in the loop, so that he can deal with any potential problems, such as:

1. **Violation of Contract**: Your company's contract with the other company may have specified a SLA (service-level agreement) or other communication protocol to be followed for all communication. While unofficial channels are usually much more efficient to get the work done, violation of a contract is usually a lot of trouble to deal with.
2. **Unreliable communication**: It is a huge risk to your client's project if the only interface with the other company is you and your friend. Their project could slow down to a crawl or even grind to a halt if either of you is unavailable. Since the work is getting done and clients are not complaining, your manager probably doesn't know (or care enough) at this point *how* the work is getting done. By letting your manager know that you are using unofficial contacts, you give him a chance to plan for such situations.
3. **Bypassing metrics**: Management loves to track "metrics", especially in deals with other companies. Using personal contacts prevents them from getting the metrics they might be interested in. During an audit or at the end of the project, they might be "pleasantly surprised" to know that they have raised zero issues with the other company, which is misleading.
4. **Dealing with problems**: It is possible that your friend could give you wrong contact information, or that the contact suggested by him creates some issues for the client. Dealing with client complaints are a part of manager's job, but they cannot do it effectively if they have no idea what is going on.

---

The actual answer ends above. The below <s>fluff</s> additional commentary is only for <s>entertainment</s> information. It is based on my real work experience (and not taken from an HR handbook), and may not apply to every situation.

Many companies prohibit their employees from contacting employees of client/vendor companies directly, for a number of reasons:

1. **Avoid bypassing management's priorities**: When requirements come through the official communication channels, it is easier for management to prioritize the tasks. Every customer wants *their* issue to be given the highest priority, but *nothing* will get done when everything is urgent. Management assigns priority to prevent such chaos. By contacting the lower level employees directly, you bypass the management, which can create problems.
2. **Avoid perception of preferential treatment**: Allowing personal contacts for communication means companies that do not have such personal contacts in the company will have to wait longer or get inferior service. Even if that is not true, the company's *other* customers will carry that perception if they find out about this personal contact arrangement.
3. **Official contacts are well trained for the job**: Why do companies send spokespersons to press conferences instead of any random employee? How do these spokespersons respond "no comment" without batting an eyelid to controversial questions? Representing your company to outsiders is serious business, for which the company trains them thoroughly.

   When things go well, using personal contacts instead of the official channels doesn't do any harm, but when things are not so rosy, such personal contacts can create problems for the company. What happens when the personal contact doesn't give you the required information, or gives the wrong information? What if you say something rude which damages your company's relationship with the other company?
4. **Prevent accidental divulgence of confidential information**: Personal contacts in companies have varying levels of awareness of corporate policies. A somewhat naive employee could unintentionally divulge company confidential information to outsiders.

Comment: That's a fair enough point, I suppose a way to restate the aspect you've called out is "Is it appropriate to use my own initiative to solve the problem if these communication channels have not been properly defined?" The information I acquire can then be put in the knowledge database so we are aware how to communicate. BUT, it introduces the risk that higher management already negotiated a channel that hasn't filtered down to us, and something in the way we independently attempt to make contact contravenes that negotiation.

Comment: @Bruno That is correct, many companies have rules that prevent employees from having contact with other companies through unauthorized channels. I will write about that in more detail later. It is usually ok for you to maintain a database of information internal to your own company, but I would strongly discourage you from having unauthorized contact with other companies even for official purposes, without keeping your manager in loop.

Comment: In my experience, I have found personal communication to be much more reliable than communication through official channels, due to people forming emotional attachments. While this answer does sound over-the-top for smaller companies, it provides a useful point of view.

Comment: This answer reads like it was pulled from HR's employee handbook. Like most games in life, the game called "the workplace" is all about knowing which rules can be bent, and which can be broken. If I used official channels every time I needed information from a vendor, or needed a coworker in another department to help me, I would literally never get anything done because I would sitting around waiting 40 hours per week.

Comment: Good lord. “I know someone who might know about that, I’ll ask them.” Absent any legal restrictions, anything beyond that is at best pointless overthinking, and at worst the kind of jobsworth busybody nonsense that slows everyone else down.

Comment: This information is completely not applicable in many scenarios.  Official channels are often intended to handle the bulk of cases, and to reliably work.  Unofficial channels can, in some cases, work much more quickly, and the best approach can sometimes be to utilize those options.  I've definitely had leadership be thankful of my ability to use back channels.  (I do agree, sometimes such an approach is not appropriate.  However, in other cases, it definitely is.  Details may vary between organizations.)  I decided not to downvote because of the exact reason given by @svavil

Comment: @Snowman The answer was based on my real work experiences, and not pulled from any HR handbook. (I take that as a compliment, by the way, since English is my *fifth* language.) I have now reorganized the answer to focus more on what I actually wanted to emphasize. I hope you like it. :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite On re-reading my answer, I realized that it does read too over-the-top. That was not my intention, however. I started off by writing "background material" before coming to the point, which unintentionally led to making the answer look like all hell will break loose if you contact someone unofficially. I hope you will like this version better. :)

Comment: @svavil Thanks for taking the time to read my answer and offering feedback. I have now reorganized the answer to be more in line with what I intended to emphasize, and less on the background material. I hope we can be more in agreement now. :)

Comment: @TOOGAM You are right, I have now updated the answer based on the feedback to focus more on the solution, and less on the background material. I hope this reads better now. :)

Answer (score 34):

> Can I pass this info along and say I got it from a personal contact in
>   the other organisation?

Yes you can pass this information along. It's not even necessary to indicate where you got the information.

However, constantly bugging your friends for information is a burden on them that could get old fast. Make sure you thank them and try to limit the times you need their help. See if you can find other sources of information, if this is going to be a recurring request.

Comment: *It's not even necessary to indicate where you got the information.*  +1 For this sentence.

Comment: I agree with this one, your personal contacts are part of your total sum of knowledge just like your notes  and education. Like those the skill is knowing when to use that resource.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good points already brought up, there sounds to be the possibility of stepping on someone else’s toes. Not everyone is receptive to unasked for help, not at least unless they are are under time pressure or are otherwise stuck.

Make the offer and **ask** rather than assume they would like you to make the call. If you are on the same level as their supervisor, then make the offer to them, because they may be using this as a learning experience to build confidence and experience, which spoon feed answers don't provide.

A lot depends on your company culture and your position within the organisation, as well as how regulated your job is and needs to be.

In some circumstances and companies networking with friends and past colleagues is actively encouraged and is part of what you bring to the table.

Of course this presumes this isn't all just an excuse not to do the work you should be doing! Distracting yourself from something boring and/or hard doesn't go well in the end, despite the temptation! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is a good idea because what if your information proves to be incorrect? Who's fault will it be?
Even though your friend may be knowledgeable, it is possible that they misunderstand your question. You will end up in a very awkward position if something goes wrong.

Comment: Uh... yours, clearly? Just because you got information from a reliable source doesn't mean you don't need to test it. That applies regardless of where you got the information, including from the official documentation (official project documentation has been wrong on *innumerable* occasions.)

Comment: I feel like "Not sure why it doesn't work - we implemented it according to the official documentation" is a much better position to be in than "yeah my mate said it should work I dunno"

Comment: @EdmundReed I much prefer being in the second situation; I'm likely to get the further information I need to fix the problem faster.

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I would encourage a subordinate to find a solution to an answer to a question or solve a problem. 'Thinking outside the box' sometimes requires thinking out of the four walls of your company. I would use whatever resources were needed as long as it did not compromise your position or current work your company is doing. In short, it is one of those questions where where the answer truly depends on the employer.